# Is before_action in application controller executed before routes.rb and models are loaded?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rails-engines

For a `before_action` in Rails engine's application controller, when a user requests an action from the engine, is the `before_action` executed before engine's `routes.rb` and `models` are loaded (or some procedure/tool which allows us to find out the executing order. Debug seems to be skipping the routes.rb and model definitions)?

```
class ApplicationController < ApplicationController

    before_action :setup_some_variable
    ..........
end
```

The purpose of `setup_some_variable` is to set variables which will be used in `routes.rb` and `models` in the engine.

Or an engines's `routes.rb` and `models` are loaded when the `main_app` is launched. Here the main app's `routes.rb' mounting a Rails engine:

```
Myapp::Application.routes.draw do

  mount MyEngine::Engine => "/my_engine"

end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Routes are loaded on application startup, and models are loaded using the Autoloader so the first time they are referenced in your code.

`before_action` runs before any controller action is run, so after the request has been routed to the correct controller action.

The Rails booting process is documented here: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/railties/lib/rails/application.rb#L37

Comment: The booting document is a good reference. `models are loaded using the Autoloader so the first time they are referenced in your code`, Usually what's defined as first time to reference a model? Usually only controllers will reference the model with action such as index, new and edit.

Comment: Also are routes and models definition loaded once in the app and be used many time late after?

Answer (score 1):

```
# config/initializers/my_engine_patch.rb

Rails.application.config.to_prepare do
  MyEngine::ApplicationController.class_eval do
    before_action :your_method

    private

    def your_method
      # your code here
    end
  end
end
```